# Use PopupWindow.setWindowLayoutType() on API < 23

Tags: android

It says method call requires API level 23. My code below,
[image]

---

But it is not possible because, following is from android official  android.widget.Editor.java source file in API 19.
[image]

Also associated constants TYPE_APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL was added from api level 1. Also I used this successfully on Xamarin under api 14.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It simply show that `setWindowLayoutType` method does not available for API level 14.

you have to add API level condition.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
{
   mContainer.setWindowLayoutType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you install api 23 sdk? You must download from android sdk manager.